# Asp.net MVC Ajax call button to retrieve single data from database

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I have this Ajax.ActionLink Button

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current"
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"})
```

this is the controller :

```
    public PartialViewResult BtnNext()
    {
        List<Queue> model = db.Queues.ToList();
        return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
    }
```

Basically when I click the Ajax button it show the whole table data in my database,
what I want to do is whenever I Click this button it shows the first data in my database and when I click it again , shows the second data.. and so on. Is that possible? thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Add param count in Action Link, count = -1 init:

```
x.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", new { count= count + 1, new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current"
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1"})
```

In Controller

```
 public PartialViewResult BtnNext(int count = 0)
        {
            //retrive record with order count
model = GetRecordWithOrder(count);
            return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
        }
```

Comment: The model is of List<T>, should be a simple .ElementAt() be sufficient?

Comment: @Rai Vu is that incomplete?

Comment: can u complete it somehow? i wanna test

Comment: You should write the method to get record